# NSData datawithcontentsoffile returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

i have below code for getting a file from iphone's documents directory:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSString *realpath;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

realpath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:
          [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"2_program.db"]];
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: realpath ] == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"find file");
    NSData *uploadedData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:realpath];
    NSString * uploadedDataBase64= [NSString base64forData:uploadedData];
    NSLog(@"base64: %@",uploadedDataBase64);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

filemanager finds the file but nsdata returns null however both of them got the same path

my file's size about 60kb

any ideas why could it be happen? am i missing somthing?

Comment: Use `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` to get information about the reason for the failure.

Comment: What is the file path? Does it have the `file://` scheme or not?

Comment: Does your `uploadedData` returns result or just your `uploadedDataBase64` returns nil?

Comment: the problem is in "base64forData" method

Comment: i check witg options:error and error is null. Also check uploadeddata and it returns "<>" only

Comment: @ercan: That means that the file exists and is empty.

Comment: sorry it can be empty my db name for query is different. ok will check the db file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip) great NSData+Base64 category by Matt Gallagher along with the code below

```
    NSString *realpath=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"2_program.db"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:realpath]){
    NSLog(@"find file");
    NSData *uploadedData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:realpath];
    NSString *uploadedDataBase64=[[[NSString alloc]initWithData:uploadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];
    NSLog(@"base64: %@",uploadedDataBase64);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

code what you have written over here looks OK,
I would suggest you to choose other method which required instance of NSError also.

```
               `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:`
```

As you will try to convert that file content into NSData if thing goes wrong then still you will get some error description and that error description may helpful to you.

I hope it may helpful to you...... cheer

Answer (score -1):

```
realpath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:
      [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"2_program.db"]];
```

here u have missed a / 
change the above statement to

```
realpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
      [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"/2_program.db"]];
```

Comment: `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` automatically puts in the path separator.

Comment: Check the documentation for the [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathComponent_): "**Return Value**
A new string made by appending aString to the receiver, **preceded if necessary by a path separator**".

Comment: So it will add the separator.

Comment: @JeremyP haven't u seen the example table in the link u provided. the / is there in every example

Comment: The top row of the table is the example of `[@"/tmp" stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"scratch.tiff"]` and the answer you get is `@“/tmp/scratch.tiff”`.  Note how the method has added a path separator in by itself.